# How do I know if user has cancelled subscription or not if user deletes app before subscription expires in iOS?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I have implemented monthly subscription in my iOS app. When user makes purchases, I am saving the data like expiration date, product id etc on my local server. If user deletes app and do not cancel the subscription, how can I know user is still in premium mode. Is there any way to track the purchase when there is no app installed on iPhone?

Comment: Have you tested this scenario on your backend? User != device. The user can install the app on another device and use it there with the same Apple ID. The Apple server should continue delivering notifications to your backend (if configured) and have correct information about the subscription.

Comment: @lazarevzubov When you said "The user can install the app on another device...." This is not what I need. I mean the app is not installed anywhere.
Do you mean we can configure our backend with Apple to get the updates?

Comment: Yes, I understand that this is not the case you mean, but my point is that subscriptions should work regardless. And I was thinking about these notifications: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications (Sorry, I don't have full information about how exactly it works, I only remember that it somehow worked on one of my past projects.)

Comment: Why do you need to know if the user is still subscribed? From what I understand, you won't use this information anywhere (you don't have a server and only your app seems to unlock your content), which means this information is useless to you, right?

Comment: @romainsalles This information is needed only for support purpose or to keep track of purchases from our backend.

Comment: Ok, so if you do have a server, use the S2S (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications) to know in real time if a user cancel their subscription: warning, it's quite hard to implement. If you only want to check the info for a given user contacting you, then you don't have to implement S2S and you only need to request Apple manually when you need it. Depending on which version of StoreKit you're using, you'll need to use https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/verifyreceipt (v1) or https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi (v2).